# Could be experience Time without any changes in our enviroment?

Tags: time

Being a beginner in Physics, I found this question to be interesting which came in mind.

Time has been expressed as an dimension which is scalar in nature. Also the GTR also explains Time Dilation.

> But, suppose, a person is kept in a room which is totally dark and
>   closed. Will he ever whether its evening or morning i.e time. If by
>   some means, our enviroment changes faster than we think that the time
>   went *faster*. Could time be relative with respect to change in our
>   environment.

When we see the world around us, through constant interaction with our environment, we realize changes in its nature. Without these changes ( as expressed in the example ), will be ever experience or feel the advancement or progress of time?

Comment: the changes are also happening in you. If your body exists to observe the universe, so does the time for you. no matter how well you will shield yourself from outside of the universe.

Comment: My view would be *no*, there is no passage of time without a change in spatial state.

Comment: look at http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/time.html#c1 and http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Therm/entrop.html  . It is not something that can be answered in a page her

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I mean, in that literal case, psychologists have actually done the experiments: it involves using old military bunkers and fallout shelters: they pay people to live inside for a little while unconnected to any outside indication of time. These are reported in Dr. James Maas’s book *Power Sleep* for example.

It turns out, when you do this, humans naturally settle into a rhythm where they go to sleep one hour later each night. In other words, we have an internal biological clock, also known as a circadian rhythm (from the Latin phrase for “around a day”). This is also why traveling across many time zones is hard. This 25-hour-day effect is very well known as well to college freshmen as it is the reason that they stop going to morning classes a few weeks in.

Incidentally things get complicated because we mutate our environment. The above 25 hour day assumes that you have explicit or implicit access to the light switches. Psychologists also discovered that if you make the entire bunker into a uniformly-dimly-lit space, people actually will go to bed an hour *earlier* every night, living out a 23-hour day.

Now, it is clear that we are big complex beings who can do things like count to approximately an hour with a combination of our counting and our hands. We are too “big” to have insight on what the universe at its most basic does.

Some physicists suspect that any configuration of mass $m$ could potentially realize (in some configuration that may not be its present one) a clock of precision $mc^2/h,$ where $c$ is the speed of light and $h$ is Planck's constant. This is based on a funny argument, so other physicists don't accept it always, but it is that a vibration with a certain frequency comes in energy lumps proportional to that frequency, and rest mass is a lump of energy. You might see how those do not have to be logically connected at all but they do “smell similar” in some strange way.

A branch of mathematical physics called QFT makes this connection slightly stronger. In QFT there are different ways to introduce a mass parameter, one is as an intrinsic mass of a particle, the same way Newton thought about it, and the other is to introduce a field of force throughout space, and allow the particle to jostle this field whenever it moves through it, which can slow it down and give it an effective mass. Indeed in the subfield that I was trained in, condensed matter, we used this trick all the time, saying that electrons in solids have some effective mass larger than their real one due to all of these interactions with the atoms in the solids averaging out. And the force field in QFT also tends to be quantized into particles.

One can imagine that maybe all mass works this way: that maybe, secretly, every particle in the universe is timeless, and moves at the speed of light through it, but like light through glass, their interactions with each other create effective descriptions where things move slower than the speed of light and appear to have mass, because they interact with each other over a certain time or length scale. And that sounds very close to what you're talking about, where for individual particles some sort of spatial configuration might be necessary to actually witness time. But there are a lot of assumptions needed to make that happen.